# How to type special characters in Fuchsia OS running on qemu?

Tags: terminal, qemu, fuchsia

I am not able to type the characters like ! @ ie characters that are printed using shift in Fuchsia terminal running in qemu.
Also can anyone  tell me how to scroll in the terminal for the same?